# hashCode() and key hash in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable, hashcode

Assume `String A = "c"`, `Character B = 'c'`.

I understand that `A.hashCode() == B.hashCode()` but `A.equals(B) == false`.

However, if you put `A` into a `HashMap` as a key. Then calling `hashMap.contains(B)` returns false although they have the same `hashCode`. Here's how Java implements some functions in `HashMap`.

```
public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
    return getNode(hash(key), key) != null;
}
static final int hash(Object key) {
    int h;
    return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
}
```

As you can see `HashMap` is simply operating on key's `hashCode()` only. Then why the `contains()` could return `false`?

Comment: Are you sure `A.equals(B)` is true?

Comment: Why do you think it's "operating on key's hashCode only"?  `key` gets passed to `getNode`, too, not just its hash code.

Comment: The overloaded `equals` method in `String` converts the given parameter into `String`, so you can't pass the character `B` directly to the `equals` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First `A.equals(B)` is false moreover `String.equals(Object o)` has this code

```
if (anObject instanceof String) {
 //comparing strings
} 
return false;
```

Also `containsKey()` calls `getNode()` which uses `equals` to distinguish between equal objects and objects with same hashCode (hash collisions).

Answer (score 1):

> why the contains could return false?

`getNode`  may return `null`. It means that the node with the `key` is not found. The hash function is just hashing the `key` that is not available in the `HashMap`.